# Understanding liquid-liquid phase separation

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential, phase-diagram

[image]

The above figure shows how the regular-solution free energy might lead to liquid–liquid equilibrium. In the region between the compositions $x^I_A$ and $x^{II}_A$, $G$ increases with $x_A$. If the overall concentration lies between these two values, it is always favorable for the
system to spontaneously phase-separate into two regions, one with composition $x^I _A$ and
another with composition $x^{II} _A$. The common tangent line gives the free energy of the phase-separated state.

Okay, so if I have solution with composition between $x^I_A$ and $x^{II}_A$, it will phase separate into whichever potential well they are closes to. That makes sense.

The above graph is just for illustration purposes. It is not directly related to the problem I have.

---

My question is, if I have an expression for the excess Gibbs energy of the Margules kind, given by,
$$G^{ex} = RT(c x_1 + kc x_2)x_1x_2$$
how do I find the region where the solution will spontaneously phase separate?
I know $G = G^{ideal}+G^{ex}$, so $G = \mu_1 + \mu_2 + RT\ln x_1 + RT\ln x_2 + G^{ex}$.

I believe that solution will most definitely spontaneously phase out when
$$\frac{\partial ^2 G}{\partial x_1^2} < 0 $$
I can solve for values of $c$ for which the solution separates.

If, however, $c$ is dependent on temperature, such as $c=wT$, how would I find the critical composition and temperature? Would I still impose
$$\frac{\partial ^2 G}{\partial x_1^2} < 0? $$
But that is only one constraint I have, but I need to solve for $T_c$ and $x_c$.

How do I go ahead with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the Margules equation is consistent with the behavior in your figure?  Have you actually plotted G/(x1x2) vs x1 to confirm this?

Comment: @ChetMiller, thanks for your reply. the figure was just to illustrate how I am understanding free energy vs composition curves. The Margules' equation and the figure are not related

Comment: I mean is can the Margules equation be qualitatively consistent with your figure?

Comment: @ChetMiller, I don't think so. The $G$ in Margules is quadratic in $x_1$, so it cannot have the quintic-like behavior we see

Comment: Have you tried plotting $G$ for the expected values of the constants at different temperatures to gain physical insight? Do multiple minima exist that would correspond to phase separation? I think this would make a more useful image in your question than the current figure.